# Magento how to call phtml file as a block on cms page?

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.9.1 and trying to create a product link directly on cms page.I have created a custombutton.phtml file and add button code here.

```
<?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>
<a class="animated infinite swing btn btn-yellow btn-lg m-r-2" role="button" href="abc.com/checkout/cart/add?product=401&qty=1&form_key=<?php echo $formKey ?>">Add to cart</a>
```

Now i am calling this phtml file as block on cms page.

```
  {{block type="core/template" name="custombutton" template="custombutton.phtml"}}
```

But sometimes it is showing button and sometimes not. Not getting the issue.

Comment: i think issue happens when block get cached.

Comment: Cache are disabled on website.

Answer (score 0):

Please give rights to block goto->system->permissions->block
and add your block name. Hope this helps

Comment: block type="core/template" is allowed by default